# How do I write regexp for the last occurence of single whitespace in Go?

Tags: regex, go

I would like to replace the last single whitespace in a string with something else. How can I write regular expression for the last whitespace in Golang? So far I've only figured out that `\s+` matches all whitespaces

Comment: Like `\s$`?....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regular expression:

```
\s(\S*)$
```

This matches a whitespace character that is followed by any non-white characters (`\S*`) up to the end of the string (`$`).

You can replace that last whitespace character like this:

```
s := "this is a string"
re := regexp.MustCompile(`\s(\S*)$`)
s2 := re.ReplaceAllString(s, "-$1") // "this is a-string"
```

The `$1` is the captured group `(\S*)`, to preserve the rest of the content after the space. Just replace the "-" character with whatever you want to replace the whitespace character with.